# Do I need ubuntu-desktop if I'm using i3?

Tags: i3-wm, distro-recommendation, tiling

I've found that I like using i3-wm manager and now I never use GNOME, which is the base distro I have installed.

I'm wondering if I want to do a fresh install and I know I want to use a tiling window manager, if I install Ubuntu-Server instead of Ubuntu-Desktop and then install i3 will I be missing a lot of components needed for using GUI applications?

Comment: If you install those applications using the package manager, then the required components will be installed by the package manager.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a desktop package to run GUI applications.

Try to do the Ubuntu Server install with all the things you need. The dependencies will be loaded automatically. If that doesn't fit your needs, revert.